# Web extension to modify uploaded file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way for a web extension (chrome or firefox) to intercept and modify a file the user has chosen to upload somewhere?

More specifically, i'm interested in striping out certain personal identifying information.

Comment: I am confused as to the question?  If I was writing a back-end server to search and delete a text string *secure* located in the document, I would write a script to upload the document in js, back-end would probably be python because I'm more familiar with Flask than Node.  Then it would verify the file type as one of my approved file types, open the file up and search for text string, delete it, then save the file as a the same name with a different time stamp.  That's what I would do, but maybe I'm missing your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about this, the functionality I'm looking to implement needs to be entirely on the client side. There is no back-end. It needs to work across every website. Hence the need for a browser extension.

Comment: I'm also interested in this usecase, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, but I didn't investigate much further.